How to drag WPF window using mouse events on HTML element inside Webview2 control
I have web application which is develop is Angular and it is running inside WPF application using WebView2 control.
Default WPF Window title is not required because application header is developed in angular app and it is achieved using WindowChrome, all caption controls are also working using webview2 send/receive message feature.
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1" 
    xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Style="{StaticResource windowStyle}">
<Grid>
    <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView" />
</Grid>

<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="windowStyle" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>

private async void InitializeWebViewAsync()
{
   var webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync();
   await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);
   webView.Source = new Uri(@"http://localhost:4200");

   webView.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += WebMessageReceived;
}

private void WebMessageReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string action = e.TryGetWebMessageAsString();

    if(action == "close")
    {
        Close();
    }
    else if(action == "minimize")
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
}

I am facing issue, when I want to drag application window using application header which is div HTML element inside angular app.
I tried 2 approaches

Send message to webView2 control when mousedown event is triggered on div tag and called DragMove() method in WPF Window class,
 if(action == "drag")
 {
     DragMove();
 }



This approach is not working with following exception

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Can only call DragMove when primary mouse button is down.


Overlay user control on webview2 control, so mousedown event can be triggered on WPF Window level. this can't also be done because of this issue.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
